# Why will all of a sudden req.body be empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

So I've been working on this React/Node application since August now. Never encountered such issue. Been trying to fix, but it just wouldn't happen.
So React is sending an Axios request to Express, and in the first middleware Tier req.body is empty. I tried to change headers back and forth. So changing them to urlencoded actually turns the req.body into this {'entire stringified payload':''} so as if it's an object with a stringified JSON payload as the property name. Setting the headers as application/json doesn't do anything.

```js
(async function(x) {
    await Axios.post(`https://${x}/dispositionController/executeDisposition`,payload)
})(this.props.correctEndpoint)
```

This is the piece of code that is sending data to Express. I didn't want to make it an IIFE, I tried many things, and made it an IIFE out of desperation. This is middleware tier in Express where req.body is empty it is actuall the first middleware tier after error-handling middleware tier for http.

```js
dispositionController.use((req,res,next)=>{
  console.trace(req.body,'req.body here');
  console.trace(req.body.Note,'req.body.Note');
  throw new Error('');
  global.thisSocket.to(`${req.body.dispoSocketID}`).emit('postingDispo');
  req.body.Note=req.body.Note.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,"");

  switch(req.body.eventID) {
    case 5:
    req.body.typeOfRegular='Inbound';
    break;
    case !5:
    req.body.typeOfRegular='Outbound';
    break;
  }
  next();
})
```

Please help.

Comment: did you checked the network tab and inspected the payload to check everything is ok from client?

Comment: are you using body parser?

Comment: Yes, using bodyParser. Nothing in Network tab... The strange thing is that I've been using this Axios thing for months with no issues, and all of a sudden just plain not working... Very unreliable. console.trace is showing this when I toggle content-type to form urlencoded, {{'.... the whole stringified JSON'}:''}. So the property name is my stringified JSON which is equal to an emptry string. Isn't making much sense...

Comment: Solved issue the dumb way. Just put jQuery in the window object. Worked from first try. Really been wasting time with this Axios thing.

Comment: The request in the network tab doesn't show the payload? Are you sure the payload isn't `undefined` when it's passed to axios.post?